# How to transfer information between pages using onclick but without using the URl

Tags: php, onclick

I have a website that builds the PHP page based on entrees in the SQL database.

For each SQL entrée a table row is created, in that row there are a few buttons, each button on the row will send you to another page.

Currently it looks like this

```
<td><center><input type=\"button\" name=\"Export screen\" value=\"Export screen\" onclick=\"window.open('/Export/ExportMainPage.php?id=".$g_id."','ExportScreen')\"> </div></center></td>
```

The issue is the **?id=** part, I want to transfer the information (**$g_id**) from this page to the ExportMainPage.php but I don't want people to be able to edit the **$g_id** value.

The page can have 20 up to 500 rows of information and OnClick events.
I tried to use  ***session_start();***

```
<td><center><input type=\"button\" name=\"Export screen\" value=\"Export screen\" onclick=\"$_SESSION['G_Id']=\".$g_id.\";window.open('/Export/ExportMainPage.php','ExportScreen')\"> </div></center></td>
```

but this generates an error :

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /var/www/vhosts

I tried using a form:

```
<form action='/Export/ExportMainPage.php' method='post' target='ExportScreen'> <input type='hidden' name='Get_Value' value='".$g_id."' /> <input type='submit' value='Export'> </div></center></td>
```

But that resulted that the

```
 $GetValue = $_POST['Get_Value'];
```

on the next page just received the last value

Any help and advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass by array to POST
`<input type='hidden' name='Get_Value[]' value="x">`

and use `foreach($_POST['Get_Value'] as $value)`
to see the all the values

Comment: This won't work, each button must send an unique value to the other page.
placing the values in an array, an reading the array on the target page doesn't help, the target page needs 1 value, based on this value the information to be displayed is collected for the SQL

Comment: Sorry so I didn't understand what you need

Comment: I trid to add a picture, but aren't allowed yet

that would explain a bit more I think